# Problem installing plugin: unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION

Tags: plugins, installation, debug

i am trying to install plugin [tumblrize](http://tumblrize.ijulien.com/) and got the error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION in
>   D:\Projects\Websites\jiewmeng\wp-content\plugins\tumblrize\tumblrize.php
>   on line 636 Call Stack: 0.0005 332520
>   1. {main}() D:\Projects\Websites\jiewmeng\wp-admin\plugins.php:0
>   0.2249 3035904 2. plugin_sandbox_scrape()
>   D:\Projects\Websites\jiewmeng\wp-admin\plugins.php:160

on line 636 is

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'tumblrize_activate');
```

i dont see anything wrong with that, just learnt to develop plugins and that line looks ok? there is the function on line 611

```
function tumblrize_activate () { ...
```

i am using wordpress 3.0.1 + PHP 5.3.2 btw

Comment: This is a situation where you want to contact the plug-in developer directly.  We don't know the Tumblrize plug-in and, as an *extension* to WordPress this falls along the lines of a solve-my-specific-site-problem (http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59/should-wordpress-answers-be-a-solve-my-specific-problem-site) question rather than a general WordPress development or administration question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now this one was really really hard to notice bug. I basically brutforced it by cutting/pasting blocks of code.

Long story short - [line 462](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tumblrize/tags/1.4.2/tumblrize.php#L462) has wrong code opening tag `<?` instead of `<?php`. Which causes some kind of cascading tag mismatch, which seems to go unnoticed by any kind of syntax checker, but wreaks havoc on execution.

Comment: do you know if the plugins trac is checked for that?

Comment: @hakre I have no remote idea, I spend little time on trac other than getting links to sources when I want to refer to those.